# i had installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with / 10 GB, swap 16 GB, and /home 81 GB now fol error occurs (Low Disk Space on Filesystem Root)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem

I had low disk space on "Filesystem root" [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7lxk.jpg) in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, please help me in resizing the `/` partition and note that I am new to Linux. My system is dual boot with for Linux partitions:

- `/` - 10 GB
- `/home` - 81 GB
- `/swap` - 16 GB

Comment: If it's a new installation I would start over again with a fresh install putting everything on `/` of 107 GB. I wouldn't create a dedicated swap partition but rather a swap file within `/`.

Comment: Agree with above.  If you want to partition things then give / at least 20 GB. Swap is only a token these days and I would keep it to 2 GB if you want one.

Comment: For now, you can shrink your `/home` and give some space to `/` but I agree with above too. You can have a separate `/home` but `/swap` is not much use now.